# What do the symbols M and N mean in this definition of lambda terms?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am learning lambda calculus from the book https://www.irif.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/biblio/Selinger-Lambda-Calculus-Notes.pdf and do not understand the meaning of the following symbols.

The definition of the lambda terms is:

Lambda terms: $\mathit{M,N} ::= x | (M N) | (λx.M) $

The question is, what do $\mathit{M}$ and $\mathit{N}$ mean?

Comment: @dkaeae I've seen you add Mathjax into titles in a few edits, where I do not think it was nessecary. I recommend against using Mathjax in titles unless nessecary: titles appear in quite a few places where Mathjax is not rendered, for one. Please have a look at [my advice on this](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1440), thanks. (Do not see this as a discouragement to editing, btw. Your edits usually are good and your effort is much appreciated!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the page following the supposedly cryptic notation:

> The above Backus-Naur Form (BNF) is a convenient abbreviation of the following equivalent, more traditionally mathematical definition:
>
> **Definition.** [...]

In said definition, it is stated that $M$ and $N$ are simply arbitrary lambda terms. (In a nutshell, it is an [inductive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_definition).)

As to why the author prefers this notation, it is stated right after the definition:

> Comparing the two equivalent definitions, we see that the Backus-Naur Form is
>   a convenient notation because: [...] the use of distinct meta-symbols for different syntactic classes ($x$, $y$, $z$
>   for variables and $M$, $N$ for terms) eliminates the need to explicitly quantify over
>   the sets [of variables and lambda terms].

Comment: Does lambda terms consist of constant, application and lambda abstraction? What does the author try to explain?

Comment: "Does lambda terms consist of constant, application and lambda abstraction?" Yes, this follows directly from the definition (since, as I have mentioned, it is an inductive definition). "What does the author try to explain?" I am afraid I do not understand your question. To which part of the text are you referring to?

Comment: what is the meaning of the symbol $\mathit{Λ}$ in The set of lambda
terms is the smallest subset $Λ ⊆ A∗$ on the page 12 at very beginning ?

Comment: $\Lambda$ denotes the set of lambda terms (since $\Lambda$ is a subset of $A^\ast$ and it is the smallest subset with the properties that follow). This kind of phrasing is pretty standard in mathematical texts.

Comment: It seems, that I must learn first discrete math to understand all these symbols, because I haven't math background.

Comment: What is your suggestion, how to should I learn lambda calculus?

Comment: I need lambda calculus to programming in Haskell.

Comment: I have a foundation about set theory

Comment: Learning lambda calculus without some math background beyond basic set theory will certainly be challenging. I suggest you start with (propositional and first-order) logic instead; the definitions and proof ideas there bear some similarity to the theory of lambda calculus. As for learning to program in Haskell, lambda calculus may give you a better understanding of its inner workings (semantics, etc.), but there is absolutely no need to be a lambda calculus expert to program in Haskell; there are plenty of good tutorials online for that (e.g., [this one](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90090/discussion-between-zero-coding-and-dkaeae).